# Matlab performance sum and loop

Tags: matlab, performance, convolution

I am trying to implement a function that mimics a 2d convolution on a picture https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d. I am not allowed to use a library for this. For a batch of pictures x(n,w,h,c), with size (50, 28, 28, 1), I calculate 32 features per pixel like so:

```
for im = 1:batch_size
    for i=1:self.shape_input(2)
        for j=1:self.shape_input(3)

            y_unagg= x_virtual(im, i:(self.pad*2+i), j:(self.pad*2+j),:,:).*self.W_hat;
            y(im,i,j,:) = reshape(sum(sum(sum(y_unagg, 2), 3), 4),...
                1, 1, 1, self.shape_filter(4));
        end
    end
end
```

This takes roughly half a second. The second time around I calculate a batch with size (50, 14, 14, 32) and map it to 64 features. This time it takes 6 seconds. Is there any way I could speed this up?

Comment: Is the built-in in [`conv2`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) allowed?

Comment: Using FFT. Programming the convolution the way you are doing it is only used to teach students about it, and then teach students how FFT is orders of magnitude faster

Comment: Or you may have a look at this [FFT implementation](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31012-2-d-convolution-using-the-fft).

Comment: @AnderBiguri Could I also use FFT to compute the gradients w.r.t. the input and the weights?

Comment: @user1111652 read the theory. FFT is used because convolution transforms into multiplication in Fourier Space. Also computing the gradient of an image must be faster than the FFT, likely.